# How to join three tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have the following tables. One table for order numbers, table for items purchased, and another table for delivery status.

```
Table1(order_number)        Table2(items)         Table3(status)
        01                      0001                  shipped
        01                      0001                  delivered
        01                      0002                  shipped
        01                      0002                  delivered
```

What I want for my query to do is get the order number, and get one item from table2 and their status history. The query should output this.

```
Table1(order_number)        Table2(items)         Table3(status)
        01                      0001                  shipped
        01                      0001                  delivered
```

So far I am only able to get all the items but not extract only one item. Here's a sample of my code.

```
SELECT
     table2.item
   , table1.order_nr
   , tabl3.name AS status
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.order = table2.order
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.item = table3.item
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide some details about the one item you need. Otherwise sql will return all the data that satisfy your query.

Introduce a `WHERE` clause and tell sql exactly what you need to display.

For example below query will return status of Item `001`

```
SELECT 
table2.item,
table1.order_nr,
tabl3.name as status
FROM
table1
    LEFT JOIN
table2 ON table1.order = table2.order
    LEFT JOIN
table3 ON table2.item = table3.item
WHERE table2.item = 0001
```

Or as you mentioned if you need to get only one record use [`LIMIT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) keyword

```
SELECT
    table2.item,
    table1.order_nr,
    tabl3.name as status
FROM
    table1
        LEFT JOIN
    table2 ON table1.order = table2.order
        LEFT JOIN
    table3 ON table2.item = table3.item
LIMIT 1
```

This is the My SQL syntax;

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
LIMIT number;
```

Comment: Hi, what if I wanted to get the first item without having to specify? What I actually wanted to do is get the person who made the status update. If there are 2 items and the order was processed by one person only, it would count as 2 transactions of the same person because there are two items. Is there a workaround in this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Sql Server ?

Comment: My SQL I think? Updated answer. Give it a try.

Comment: I tried it. However I can't use this as the number of status updates are fixed. There could be 4 status updates in one order number, and 5 in the other.